# Issue with querying data from mongo for nested elements

Tags: c#, arrays, sitecore, mongodb-query, sitecore-mvc

I am very new to mongo db and using C# mongo driver to find some stuff. Below is my query in robo mongo which returns me the results.

```
db.getCollection('MyCollection').
find
({  
     "StartDateTime":{ $gte : ISODate("2016-12-08T00:00:00.0000Z") }, 
     "Pages.PageEvents.PageEventDefinitionId": LUUID("dd6a6fdc-a96a-3f42-a824-49uuee741aa9")
 });
```

Below is the way I am writing C# code. For `StartDateTime` it is working. But I am not sure how to look for `Pages.PageEvents.PageEventDefinitionId`. `Pages` is a collection, `PageEvents` is further a collection inside `Pages` and each `PageEvent` has a `PageDefinitonId`. `Pages` and `StartDateTime` are at same level in document.

```
var builder = new QueryBuilder<MyData>();
var filter = builder.And(builder.GTE(_ => _.StartDateTime, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30))); 
var results= driver.MyCollection.FindAs<MyData>(filter).Select(X => X);
```

Comment: are you using MongoSharp?

Comment: I am writing the code in C# langugage using MongoDB driver. I am not sure about MongoSharp.